# how to grep both files , but exclude other files

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, rhel, regular-expression

We want to search string by grep to both files:

The files are

```
/confluent/logs/server.log
/confluent/logs/server.log.1
```

But we not want to match the other files as

```
/confluent/logs/server.log.2
/confluent/logs/server.log.3
```

etc

So instead to do double grep as

```
grep log.retention.bytes  /confluent/logs/server.log
grep log.retention.bytes  /confluent/logs/server.log.1
```

we want to find the match of `log.retention.bytes`  on both files on the same time

we try to do

```
grep log.retention.bytes   /opt/mcspace/confluent/logs/server.log.*[1]
```

but this is wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
grep log.retention.bytes server.log{,.1}
```

In order to keep log entries (appended) in chronological order, you might want to reverse the order of files:

```
grep log.retention.bytes server.log{.1,}
```

which is of course equivalent to:

```
grep log.retention.bytes server.log.1 server.log
```

as the brace expansion is done by the shell before executing the `grep` command.

Moreover, with `zsh` shell you can easily automatically glob for the *last N files matching a pattern* with:

```
grep log.retention.bytes server.log*(Om[-2,-1])
```

where `Om` means *order by mtime descending* and `[-2,-1]` fetches 2 last rows. This trick is worth remembering if you watch to search more files and do not want to type them manually.

Comment: with your answer you can get score 100 or more

Comment: Please note that although accidental matches are unlikely in this case, I would recommend to escape the `.` in the regular expressions since they are to match literal `.` in the files ...

Comment: Shell expansion doesn't use regexps (at least by default), so there's no need to escape dots.

Comment: Yes, but `grep` searches based on regexps, so at least the `log\.retention\.bytes` may warrant escaping.

Comment: Oh, the grep pattern - yes, this might be the subject of escaping, however since I don't know what the OP was exactly searching for (maybe *log-retention_bytes* as well?) this is out of the scope of my answer, I focus on shell globing for appropriate files selection as an argument to any command.

Comment: You are right, I should probably have left that comment below the question ;)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to grep in two files, is to give both files to grep:

```
grep log.retention.bytes /confluent/logs/server.log /confluent/logs/server.log.1
```

When you have more files, you can either list them all manually or use a glob that matches only your specific files. For example, in bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
grep log.retention.bytes /confluent/logs/server.log?(.1)
```

Finally, and probably most simple in your case, you can use brace expansion as shown [in Tomassz's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/599403/22222).

Comment: thank you about the effort -:)